Linear algebra applications in graph and tree search algorithms
How is linear algebra used within A* pathfinding algorithms?
I know that a graph can be
expressed as a matrix of the weights of the edges and a vector of the optimistic cost of the nodes. However I'm having trouble figuring out what kinds of matrix operations are needed to get from a matrix of weights and a vector of costs to a decision about which is the optimal path.
The particular application I am interested in is robotic path planning.

Linear algebra is not used in A* path planning. A graph can be represented as a matrix, yes, but you do not apply any arithmetic operations to the matrix. You only read from it in order to extract neighborhood relations and the cost of traversal to the neighbors.
